# Linear Algebra: The inverse of an injective function

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I have this question from multiple choice section in an old exam paper in Linear Algebra: [image: Question for Linear Algebra Exam]

As I read it, what they are saying is that if $f$ is injective then there exists an inverse function $g$.

This quote from the book Linear Algebra Done Right contradicts this:
[image: Invertibility of Linear Maps]

since injective is a nessesary but not sufficient criterion for invertibility.

I am unsure if I am reading the question right though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I read it, what they are saying is that if $ f $ is injective then
> there exists an inverse function $ g $.

That is not quite true. Notice that the domain of $ g $ is *not* equal to the codomain of $ f $, so $ g $ is not an inverse function of $ f $. Instead, it is an inverse of $ f' : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \text{im} (f) $, which does not contradict the quote from Linear Algebra Done Right, since $ f' $ is injective (because $ f $ is already injective) *and* surjective (because we defined its codomain to be equal to its image).

Comment: OK, I am quite confused because the lecturer and the book don't use the same notation, so I constantly have to translate his questions into the language of the book. He gave the class a list of notations to translate between what he uses and the book - and in there it says that $Im(T)$ in his notation is the same as $Range(T)$  in the book.